# convert data string to list

Tags: string, list, python-2.7

I'm having some troubles processing some input. 
I am reading data from a log file  and store the different values according to the name.
So my input string consists of ip, name, time and a data value. 
A log line looks like this and it has \t spacing:

```
134.51.239.54    Steven    2015-01-01 06:09:01    5423
```

I'm reading in the values using this code:

```
loglines = file.splitlines()
    data_fields = loglines[0]  # IP NAME DATE DATA
    for loglines in loglines[1:]:
     items = loglines.split("\t")
     ip = items[0]
     name = items[1]
     date = items[2]
     data = items[3]
```

This works quite well but I need to extract all names to a list but I haven't found a functioning solution.

When i use print name i get:

```
Steven
Max
Paul
```

I do need a list of the names like this:

```
['Steven', 'Max', 'Paul',...]
```

There is probably a simple solution and i haven't figured it out yet, but can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an empty list and add the names as you loop through the file.

Also note that if that file is very large, `file.splitlines()` is probably not the best idea, as it reads the entire file into memory -- and then you basically *copy* all of that by doing `loglines[1:]`. Better use the `file` object itself as an iterator. And don't use `file` as a variable name, as it shadows the type.

```
with open("some_file.log") as the_file:
    data_fields = next(the_file)     # consumes first line
    all_the_names = []               # this will hold the names
    for line in the_file:            # loops over the rest
        items = line.split("\t")
        ip, name, date, data = items # you can put all this in one line
        all_the_names.append(name)   # add the name to the list of names
```

Alternatively, you could use `zip` and `map` to put it all into one expression (using that `loglines` data), but you rather shouldn't do that... `zip(*map(lambda s: s.split('\t'), loglines[1:]))[1]`

Comment: thanks for your reply, but when I use your code i get for every line "None"
EDIT: my bad, it works